# Having Duplicate named routes definition warning on different urls

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am having this warning:

> vue-router.esm.js:16 [vue-router] Duplicate named routes definition: {
>   name: "some_url", path: "/some_url" }

Using `/!/` like:

```
{
  path: '/!/some_url',
  name: 'some_url',
  component: SomePage,
  meta: {requiresAuth: false}
},
 {
  path: '/some_url',
  name: 'some_url',
  component: SomePage,
  meta: {requiresAuth: false}
},
```

Urls are obviously different, is there something I am missing or wrongly configured?

Comment: Yes the name is the same

Comment: If you refer to a name in some router functions you get problems if you use duplicated names.